# Card Section with grid layout

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, styled-components

Hello basically i have this so far
(on mobile devices I managed to make it responsive, but on larger screens I am not able to set the height of the layout so that it is the same among all children)

on desktop:

[image]

on mobile ( ok ) :

[image]

But I can't set my height when it's not a mobile device

i want this:

[image]

code:

```
  <TestingLive>
    <div class="a">
      <span>a</span>
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      <span>b</span>
    </div>
    <div class="c">
      <span>c</span>
    </div>
    <div class="d">
      <span>d</span>
    </div>
    <div class="e">
      <span>e</span>
    </div>
  </TestingLive>
```

and my css ( with styled comp )

```
const TestingLive = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b c"
    "a d e";
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-template-columns: 40vw 1fr 1fr;

  ${media.lessThan("medium")`
  grid-template-columns:1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-template-areas:
  'a '
  'b'
  'c'
  'd'
  'e';
  `}

  margin-top: 50px;
  & > * {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
  }

  & .a {
    grid-area: a;
  }

  & .b {
    grid-area: b;
  }

  & .c {
    grid-area: c;
  }

  & .d {
    grid-area: d;
  }

  & .e {
    grid-area: e;
  }
`;
```

example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-snowflake-4dwpy

@Awais

if i use:
height: 100%; max-height: 60vh; min-height: 60 vh;

i got this

[image]

but if I only use height 60 vh
works normally

Comment: So you want on desktop to have for example `b` the same height of `a` ? Or what do you mean ? It's not really clear what you actually want.

Comment: basically that my container has 60vh
and A is 100% height
my b c is half the height
and my d and the other half

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Set height in `vh` using `calc` OR simple `height:100vh` if no extra
>   space on page like `margin` `padding` etc

```
.fHHWeb {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "a b c"
        "a d e";
    grid-gap: 4px;
    grid-template-columns: 40vw 1fr 1fr;
    margin-top: 50px;
    height: calc(100vh - 60px);
}
```

Comment: I did this: height: 100%;
  max-height: 60vh;
  min-height: 60 vh;

but for some reason my container exceeds my div

Comment: @Mykon Sorry I didnt get it from screenshot... Can you please explain a little bit OR update you question/mine ans with the latest code you tried

Comment: when I use height: 100%; max-height: 60vh; min-height: 60h

my container exceeds the maximum size and looks as if it had absolute position on top of another div

Comment: @MykonSpt In you above mention example there is some div which have padding, if you remove it and use height in calc as i mention in my ans you get the desire result.... `vh`:Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly (you wish that big tile is 60vh and small one 30vh) simply add:

```
div {
    min-height: 30vh;
  }
```

If that's not what you need please give better description and examples.

Comment: basically this is what I need my big block to have 60 vh
and my two little ones have 30 v h

but I don't know how to do this on the grid

Comment: I was thinking that it is not to define the height in the children, but in the container grid.